# Are avocado seeds edible?

Tags: food-safety, seeds, avocados

I've seen article about [great benefits of eating avocado seeds](http://omtimes.com/2012/10/13-great-benefits-of-eating-avocado-seeds/). And another [here](http://www.livestrong.com/article/31737-eat-avocado-seeds-nutrition/).

Does it mean avocado seeds are edible? How do you eat it then?

On [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado) we can read:

> Avocado leaves, bark, skin, or pit are documented to be harmful to animals; cats, dogs, cattle, goats, rabbits, rats, guinea pigs, birds, fish, and horses can be severely harmed or even killed when they consume them.

How about humans?

Somebody from [here](http://rawandliving.tribe.net/thread/bd5aa44c-4b85-4ab4-a9b3-eb8cd4418df8) suggested that the avocado pit is mildly toxic.

Comment: Page 2 of your first article, and your second article, suggest preparation methods. What I can find from the citations in the Wikipedia page (and that for Persin, the main toxin present in the avocado plant) seems to indicate it is much more harmful to birds than to mammals, and may not be present in all varieties of avocado. In my opinion none of the sources provide any particularly credible evidence of these alleged benefits, and all of them concede that it does not taste good.

Comment: I'd highly recommend against swallowing it whole.

Comment: Don't eat them. Getting your colon irrigated is no fun. Trust me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Persin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persin) is a fungicidal toxin present in the avocado which is generally harmless to humans. However when consumed by domestic animals in large quantities it is dangerous.

It is an oil-soluble compound structurally similar to a fatty acid, and it leaches into the body of the fruit from the pits. Negative effects in humans seem to be primarily in allergic individuals.

Answer (score 4):

I can't advise on any of these, so I'd normally put this in a comment, but it's a bit long.

Searching on 'how to cook avocado seeds' found a few articles on the topic:

- http://www.livestrong.com/article/31737-eat-avocado-seeds-nutrition/ : calls for grinding it in a 'powerful food processor' and warns that it might damage lesser ones.
- http://www.wisegeek.com/can-i-eat-avocado-pits.htm : calls for drying it for several days, smashing it with a hammer, and then putting it in a food processor or blender (against warning that it might damage them)
- http://eattheweeds.com/forum/index.php?topic=973.0 : mention roasting then grinding (and has links to the various reports on toxicity in animals)
- http://www.veggieboards.com/forum/188-raw-food-support-forum/138169-eating-avocado-seeds.html : mentions drying then grating it (but they were making a facial scrub, not food).
- http://www.ehow.com/how_8171238_boil-avocado-pit.html : calls for grating it (without drying) then boiling it (but this one also seems to be for facials, not eating)

The only common thing between all of these is that they call for getting it smaller before eating.  Most make it into a powder first if they're planning for consumption.  I don't know if grating it first might make it safe to go through a food processor without damage.  (or if you could grate + boil then process)

Comment: They must taste pretty good...because they don't look like anything good to eat.

Answer (score 3):

Just because something is harmful for animals, you can't conclude that it is harmful to humans. Some examples:

- Grapes and raisins can kill a dog or cat, they cause renal failure.
- Sugar alcohols which are used as artificial sweeteners in a number of foods can also kill animals, they cause a sudden drop in blood sugar which can be deadly.

So avocado seeds may or may not be toxic to humans.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the truth is avocado seeds are toxic. But that doesn't mean you can't have them. At the same time, they are helpful with lowering blood pressure and losing weight. Avocado seeds contain this toxic compound in a minuscule amount and whatever little that is present in it can be detoxified by our body easily. The only thing to note here is that moderation is key.